# UWP - Is there a File Explorer control?

Tags: .net-core, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm writing an UWP app, in C# netcore. targeting min API 1809, with VS2019

I'm trying to add a ContentDialog that performs operations with storage files. And I want to add a FileExplorer control in that dialog. For selecting multiple files.

The Controls available in the XAML library, (and in the Community Toolkit Library) seems to lack the File Explorer Control. Like shown in the following image (from a very old software):

[image: File explorer inside a dialog]

I want to add to my app something like in the image. A Visual Control for displaying files and folders, and allow to select them. Does it exists?
Please guys, I beg don't tell me to use the UWP TreeView Control because I think it sucks.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UWP - Is there a File Explorer control?

UWP does not has exactly the same control like above screenshot, but it has TreeView control that could implement similar feature. Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view) for more detail. And we also provide [Xaml Control Gallery](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/p/xaml-controls-gallery/9msvh128x2zt?rtc=1) app that you could refer.